# JPEG callback timeout when using a captureBurst on Camera2 api

Tags: java, c#, android, mono, android-camera

I'm using the camera2 api to take a sheaf of images from a captureBurst.
The app is a slightly altered version of camera2basic.

The image reader is declared:

```
ImageReader multiReader = ImageReader.NewInstance(width, height, ImageFormatType.Jpeg, 10);
```

and I'm using this cameraCaptureCallback:

```
private class CameraCaptureStateListener: CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback
{

    public Action<CameraCaptureSession> OnConfigureFailedAction;
    public override void OnConfigureFailed (CameraCaptureSession session)
    {
        if (OnConfigureFailedAction != null) 
        {
            OnConfigureFailedAction (session);
        }
    }
    public Action<CameraCaptureSession> OnConfiguredAction;
    public override void OnConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session)
    {
        if(OnConfiguredAction != null)
        {
            OnConfiguredAction(session);
        }
    }
}
```

this is the captureSession:

```
mCameraDevice.CreateCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureStateListener()
{
    OnConfiguredAction = (CameraCaptureSession session) => {
        try 
        {
            List<CaptureRequest> requests = new List<CaptureRequest>();
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                requests.Add(crBuilder.Build());
                Log.Debug("CaptureRequest", "Added new captureRequst");
            }
                session.CaptureBurst(requests, captureListener, backgroundHandler);
                Toast.MakeText (activity, "BurstCapture Complete", ToastLength.Long).Show ();
        }
        catch (CameraAccessException ex)
        {
            Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Info, "Capture Session error: ", ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}, backgroundHandler );
```

This is my error log:

```
[Adreno-EGL] <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
[Adreno-EGL] OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
[Adreno-EGL] Build Date: 02/11/15 Wed
[Adreno-EGL] Local Branch: mybranch7539026
[Adreno-EGL] Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.10
[Adreno-EGL] Local Patches: NONE
[Adreno-EGL] Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016 + 62ca4eb + acd831d + 9f8b442 + e027a02 + cba30ba + 53c303a + a649d79 + 23e16f8 + 5e97da7 + cbd2a44 + 33d072a + 7aacf06 + 72b33e7 + 28f6f60 + b4c13d8 +  NOTHING
[OpenGLRenderer] Initialized EGL, version 1.4
[OpenGLRenderer] Enabling debug mode 0
[CameraDeviceState] Legacy camera service transitioning to state CONFIGURING
[RequestThread-0] Configure outputs: 1 surfaces configured.
[Camera] app passed NULL surface
[CameraDeviceState] Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
[CameraFragment: CameraCharacteristics] lensFocusDistanceCalibration = 
[RequestQueue] Repeating capture request set.
[LegacyRequestMapper] convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[CameraDeviceState] Legacy camera service transitioning to state CAPTURING
[BufferQueueConsumer] [unnamed-24394-2] setMaxAcquiredBufferCount: invalid count 1000
[RequestQueue] Repeating capture request cancelled.
[CameraDeviceState] Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
[CameraDeviceState] Legacy camera service transitioning to state CONFIGURING
[RequestThread-0] Configure outputs: 2 surfaces configured.
[Camera] app passed NULL surface
[RequestThread-0] configureOutputs - set take picture size to 4160x3120
[CameraDeviceState] Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
[Choreographer] Skipped 1381 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
Thread started:  #3
[Mono] DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/libc.so'.
[Mono] DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/libc.so'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libc.so' ('/system/lib/libc.so').
[Mono] Searching for 'gettid'.
[Mono] Probing 'gettid'.
[Mono] Found as 'gettid'.
[CaptureRequest] Added new captureRequst
[CaptureRequest] Added new captureRequst
[CaptureRequest] Added new captureRequst
[CaptureRequest] Added new captureRequst
[CaptureRequest] Added new captureRequst
[CaptureRequest] Added new captureRequst
[CaptureRequest] Added new captureRequst
[CaptureRequest] Added new captureRequst
[CaptureRequest] Added new captureRequst
[CaptureRequest] Added new captureRequst
[LegacyRequestMapper] convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[RenderScript] Application requested CPU execution
[RenderScript] 0xb8382058 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
[CameraDeviceState] Legacy camera service transitioning to state CAPTURING
[RequestThread-0] Received jpeg.
[RequestThread-0] Producing jpeg buffer...
[ImageReader_JNI] ImageReader_imageSetup: Receiving JPEG in HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 buffer.
[LegacyRequestMapper] convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[RequestThread-0] Received jpeg.
[RequestThread-0] Producing jpeg buffer...
[LegacyRequestMapper] convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[RequestThread-0] Received jpeg.
[RequestThread-0] Producing jpeg buffer...
[LegacyRequestMapper] convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[RequestThread-0] Received jpeg.
[RequestThread-0] Producing jpeg buffer...
[RequestThread-0] Hit timeout for jpeg callback!
[LegacyRequestMapper] convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[RequestThread-0] Hit timeout for jpeg callback!
[RequestHolder] Capture failed for request: 1
[LegacyRequestMapper] convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[RequestThread-0] Hit timeout for jpeg callback!
[RequestHolder] Capture failed for request: 1
[LegacyRequestMapper] convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[RequestThread-0] Hit timeout for jpeg callback!
[RequestHolder] Capture failed for request: 1
[LegacyRequestMapper] convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[RequestThread-0] Hit timeout for jpeg callback!
[RequestHolder] Capture failed for request: 1
[LegacyRequestMapper] convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[RequestThread-0] Hit timeout for jpeg callback!
[RequestHolder] Capture failed for request: 1
[LegacyRequestMapper] convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[LegacyRequestMapper] Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
[RequestThread-0] Hit timeout for jpeg callback!
[RequestHolder] Capture failed for request: 1
[CameraDeviceState] Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
[CameraDeviceState] Legacy camera service transitioning to state CONFIGURING
[RequestThread-0] Configure outputs: 1 surfaces configured.
[Camera] app passed NULL surface
[CameraDeviceState] Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
[ImageReader_JNI] ImageReader_imageSetup: Receiving JPEG in HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 buffer.
[ImageReader_JNI] ImageReader_imageSetup: Receiving JPEG in HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 buffer.
[Legacy-CameraDevice-JNI] produceFrame: Pixel buffer needs size 1529528, cannot fit in gralloc buffer of size 1248
[Legacy-CameraDevice-JNI] LegacyCameraDevice_nativeProduceFrame: Error while producing frame Invalid argument (-22).
Thread started:  #4
```

and also FYI this is from Xamarin Studio which is why it is in c# rather than java

It would appear that because I was using xamarin to step through the code, it was not stopping all threads, and this was causing race conditions to occur between the active thread (stopped) and the jpeg buffer, which was causing the jpeg callback error.

Answer (score 2):

Modify this line in your Camera 2 API view

```
imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),ImageFormat.JPEG, 2);
```